# Using cache view false for specific transition

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I know this can false the cache in particular state or view

**Disable cache within state provider**

```
$stateProvider.state('myState', {
   cache: false,
   url : '/myUrl',
   templateUrl : 'my-template.html'
})
```

**Disable cache with an attribute**

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
  ...
</ion-view>
```

But i need to false the cache from a specific view transition for example

```
$state.go('home',{cache: false});
```

here i have to false the home state cache, I tried this but not working yet

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1)** You can pass a state param like you did in `$state.go('home',{cache: false});` and handle it in your controller's beforeEnter event. Remember to **inject $stateParams into your controller**.

```
angular.module('app.controllers', []).controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function(){
        if ($stateParams.cache === false) {
            // Do whatever you need, reload $scope data, etc
        }
    });
    ...
});
```

Furthermore, you'll need to add a description for your parameter in the router config. Pay attention to `params: {cache: null}`:

```
$stateProvider.state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    params: { cache: null },
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeCtrl'
        }
    }
});
```

**Option 2)** If you don't mind to clear cache for all views, you can use:

```
$ionicHistory.clearCache().then(function(){
    $state.go('home');
});
```

See:
[$ionicHistory.clearCache()](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicHistory/#clearCache)

Answer (score 0):

The first time a template is used, it is loaded in the template cache for quick retrieval. You can use `$templateCache` service directly to add your Template in cache or to remove it from cache. Try below example

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $templateCache) {
        $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
                if (typeof(current) !== 'undefined'){
                    $templateCache.remove(current.templateUrl);
                }
                //Or if you want to remove next state from cache
                if (typeof(next) !== 'undefined'){
                    $templateCache.remove(next.templateUrl);
                }
                 .....

        });
}
```